# How to switch default MySql driver for PHP?

Tags: php, pdo, mysql-connector, php-5.5

I am running a legacy system on the server with **PHP 5.5.38** and am trying to connect with PDO to a **MySQL 8.0** database, which results in the famous "Server sent charset unknown to the client. Please, report to the developers" error.

I've already tried sending `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND "SET NAMES 'utf8'"`, but this didn't solve the problem.

The default MySql driver is mysqlnd. I noticed that the PDO Driver for MySQL has `Client API version mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503`.

I was able to successfully connect on a different environment running **PHP 5.5.38** where the PDO Driver for MySQL has `Client API version 5.1.73` and where the default MySql driver is not mysqlnd.

Is it possible to install and switch to a different PHP MySql driver without recompiling PHP?

Comment: Why do you use such ancient PHP version? Please upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: Hi, does anyone find a solution for this? I have been stuck in a similar problem.

Answer (score -2):

Maby you should check your mysql character config, try to add or modify this in you mysql config file, and restar you mysql server.

```
[mysqld]
character-set-server = utf8
```

mysqlnd 5.0.11 can't identify MySQL 8's new Unicode types

Comment: Updating the MySql config on the MySql 8 server is not an option.